# How to extract unique values from nested lists of type string?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have below list of nested lists as strings:

```
L1 = ["['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR6', 'NR7']", "['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR6', 'NR7']", "['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR1', 'NR2', 'NR3', 'NR5', 'N
    R6', 'NR7', 'NR8']", "['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR1', 'NR2', 'NR5', 'NR6', 'NR7', 'NR8']"]
```

Here L1 is:

```
L1 = df['column_name'].tolist()
```

Each nested list here was extracted from a pandas dataframe df using tolist() function so the original dataframe had this data as:

```
column_Name
['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR6', 'NR7']
['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR6', 'NR7']
['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR1', 'NR2', 'NR3', 'NR5', 'NR6', 'NR7', 'NR8']
...
...
```

I want to join all datapoints from all nested lists of L1 after removing any duplicates. I tried using sum(L1,[]) but it doesn't work as all nested lists are strings here. Why tolist function is returning list of strings here & not list of lists? Is there a better way to get unique data from selected rows above direcly from dataframe column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
L = df['Column_Name'].apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist()
```

---

```
L = df['Column_Name'].str.strip("[']").str.split("', '").tolist()
print (L)
[['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR6', 'NR7'], 
 ['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR6', 'NR7'], 
 ['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR1', 'NR2', 'NR3', 'NR5', 'NR6', 'NR7', 'NR8']]
```

And then make [flatten list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python):

```
a = [item for sublist in L for item in sublist])
```

Last convert to `set` for unique list:

```
b = list(set(a))
print (b)
['NR7', '32', '195', '139', '54', 'NR1', 'NR2', 'NR3', 'NR6', 'NR5', 'NR8']
```

Another only pandas solution:

```
b = df['Column_Name'].str.split(", ", expand=True).stack().str.strip("[]'").unique().tolist()
print (b)
['32', '54', '139', '195', 'NR6', 'NR7', 'NR1', 'NR2', 'NR3', 'NR5', 'NR8']
```